# kubernetes setup on baremetal centos 7

Tags: centos, kubernetes

I am trying to deploy kubernetes on "CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406"
using "yum install kubernetes"
Which installs "kubernetes-0.17.1-4.el7.x86_64".

**I am unable to understand how I can get the latest stable release (which I believe is 0.20.xxx)**

I was also unable to "--enablerepo=updates-testing" which results in error as

below are the available repositories in my computer

base/7/x86_64                        CentOS-7 - Base                                                     8,652
extras/7/x86_64                      CentOS-7 - Extras                                                     149
updates/7/x86_64                     CentOS-7 - Updates                                                    928
repolist: 17,876

Answer (score 1):

The CentOS packages can be found at http://cbs.centos.org/kojifiles/packages/kubernetes.

They are maintained by a community contributors which, unfortunately, means that they sometimes lag behind the latest release until they are rebuilt.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to add custom repository to get latest Kubernetes?

Comment: I filed a github issue for you (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/issues/10722). Feel free to follow along there.

Comment: The latest packages are at http://cbs.centos.org/kojifiles/packages/kubernetes/. There is a 0.19 and a 0.20 release in that directory.

Comment: Appreciate you help on this.                                                                     I was referring to the version of kubernetes in following repository (where it is still pointing to 0.17.xx)                                http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/

Comment: With reference to the package mentioned by you, for now I have created a new repository named /etc/yum.repos.d/cbs.repo   with following lines                                                                                    [virt7-docker-common-candidate]
name=virt7-docker-common-candidate
baseurl=http://cbs.centos.org/repos/virt7-docker-common-candidate/x86_64/os/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0

Comment: This is much relevant link for what I was trying to do https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guides/centos/centos_manual_config.md

Comment: I'm not sure who maintains that repository. And the instructions that you linked to haven't been updated in a few months, so it isn't surprising that they reference an old release version.